# onChange react event doesn't work as expected on ios devices (hybrid application using Cordova wrapper)

Tags: reactjs, cordova

I have a simple React component,
it looks like this:

```
  <Select
      onChange={this.handleChangeOption}
      options={optionsToRender}
      value={value} />
```

my handleChangeOption method is the following:

```
   handleChangeOption = newValue => {
        switch (newValue) {
            case this.props.optionSelectionBrowse.value: {
                this.openMyPopupMarkup()
                break
            }
            default: {
                this.props.onChange(newValue)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

When I select 'browse' option, it handles this.handleBrowseSelection()
method (which check for string 'browse', then open popup) and doesn't change select option state value. The value of Select component should stay the same all the time.

The problem is: My hybrid application ignores the first case (on click 'done' on native select and choose 'browse' option, it opens pop up and change select state but it should open popup only). The issue is only reproducible on ios devices (tested on 12.2 - 12.4 versions). On a desktop web version or Android devices, it works fine, my change event works as expected.

Comment: What is the type of `newValue` and `this.props.optionSelectionBrowse.value`? Does it log the correct value in the console on native? `console.log(this.props.optionSelectionBrowse.value)`

Comment: yeah, the value is correct  - 'browse'. it seems hard to debug in x-code actual result of function calls in hybrid app (everything is minified). When I connect my ios simulator to web localhost version  - everything is works. All console.log's output expected result. The issue is only reproducible on hybrid application (ios devices).

Comment: You could add a `console.warn` statement, those don't get removed by running your app using `react-native run-ios`. A good start would be: `console.warn(this.props.optionSelectionBrowse.value === newValue ? 'Are Equal': 'Not Equal')`

Comment: I use npm run ios (cordova wrapper). console.warn and console.log doesn't output anything after build

Comment: How did you setup the project? Did you use `react-native init`?

Comment: I've connected to localhost my cordova hybrid app, now, it's possible to debug my app. So, nothing wrong with code, the problem is: even before my 'handleChangeOption' method executed, when I click 'done' on native ios select keyboard - it change option value in my select. Looks like 'special' behaviour of ios native select change event.